# array_length(text[]) error in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have the following Redshift query

```
SELECT
    user_uuid,
    genre,
    COUNT(*) AS occurrences,
    LISTAGG(content_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY content_id) AS content_ids_array,
    ARRAY_LENGTH(STRING_TO_ARRAY(LISTAGG(content_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY content_id), ','))::INT AS content_ids_array_length
FROM
    info_master
WHERE
    event_date BETWEEN '2023-09-01' AND '2023-09-30'
GROUP BY
    user_uuid,
    genre;
```

I keep getting an error, on the array actions I want to perform.

`ERROR: function array_length(text[]) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.`

`content_id` is of type - `character varying(256)`

Please advise how to resolve this? doesn't Redshift have proper array functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the SPLIT_TO_ARRAY() function.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/split_to_array.html

I suspect that string_to_array() function is a leader node only function that is in support of limited postgres operations needed for maintenance actions.

And you will need to use get_array_length() function. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/get_array_length.html

Comment: There's an improvement, now getting a different error "function array_length(super) does not exist Hint"

Comment: See answer update - Redshift uses get_array_length()